# Why is escaping exclamation marks not necessary in parameter of `for /F` or `for /R`?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, syntax, cmd

When [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is enabled, it is (usually) necessary to escape exclamation marks properly in order to get literal ones (like `^^!` or, when being in between `""`, `^!`, in order to get a literal `!`).

However, why is no escaping of exclamation marks necessary but even distructive within the parameters provided immediately after the `/R` or the `/F` switch of the `for` loop command?

---

With the aforementioned escaping rules in mind, I created the following batch script using `for /R` and as a parameter a directory with an `!` in its name (stated after the `/R` option):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set "TARGET=excl^!dir"
set "FILE=empty_%RANDOM%.txt"
echo/
echo creating directory: !TARGET!
mkdir "!TARGET!"
echo placing empty file: !TARGET!\%FILE%
> "!TARGET!\%FILE%" break
echo/
echo adequately escaped `^^!`:
for /R "excl^!dir" %%F in ("*.*") do echo(found item: %%~nxF
for /R excl^^!dir %%F in ("*.*") do echo(found item: %%~nxF
echo/
echo improperly escaped `^^!`:
for /R "excl!dir" %%F in ("*.*") do echo(found item: %%~nxF
for /R excl!dir %%F in ("*.*") do echo(found item: %%~nxF
for /R excl^!dir %%F in ("*.*") do echo(found item: %%~nxF

erase "!TARGET!\%FILE%"
rmdir "!TARGET!"

endlocal
exit /B
```

Surprisingly, the directory is enumerated only *without* escaping the `!`. This is an output:

> ```
> creating directory: excl!dir
> placing empty file: excl!dir\empty_18378.txt
>
> adequately escaped `!`:
>
> improperly escaped `!`:
> found item: empty_18378.txt
> found item: empty_18378.txt
> found item: empty_18378.txt
> ```

I expect the directory to be enumerated in case the exclamation mark *is* in fact properly escaped, otherwise not; but the result shows the opposite behaviour.

---

A similar phenomenon arises with `for /F`, like in the following script with an `!` in the option string:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set "STRING=EXCLAMATION ^! MARK AND CARET ^^ SYMBOL"
echo/
echo normal  expansion: %STRING%
echo delayed expansion: !STRING!
echo/
echo adequately escaped `^^!`:
for /F "tokens=1-2 delims=^!" %%K in ("!STRING!") do echo(%%K -- %%L
for /F tokens^=1-2^ delims^=^^! %%K in ("!STRING!") do echo(%%K -- %%L
echo/
echo improperly escaped `^^!`:
for /F "tokens=1-2 delims=!" %%K in ("!STRING!") do echo(%%K -- %%L
for /F tokens^=1-2^ delims^=! %%K in ("!STRING!") do echo(%%K -- %%L
for /F tokens^=1-2^ delims^=^! %%K in ("!STRING!") do echo(%%K -- %%L

endlocal
exit /B
```

The output looks like this, strangely:

> ```
> normal  expansion: EXCLAMATION  MARK AND CARET  SYMBOL
> delayed expansion: EXCLAMATION ! MARK AND CARET ^ SYMBOL
>
> adequately escaped `!`:
> EXCLAMATION  --  MARK AND CARET
> EXCLAMATION  --  MARK AND CARET
>
> improperly escaped `!`:
> EXCLAMATION  --  MARK AND CARET ^ SYMBOL
> EXCLAMATION  --  MARK AND CARET ^ SYMBOL
> EXCLAMATION  --  MARK AND CARET ^ SYMBOL
> ```

Here I expect the whole string to be split into exactly two tokens: `EXCLAMATION` and `MARK AND CARET ^ SYMBOL`. But the second token is too short, everything beginning from the caret symbol `^` is missing; so I conclude that the `^` used for escaping of the `!` is taken literally. With no (or poor) escaping, the returned tokens are the intended ones.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that requires delayed expansion. You use delayed expansion within groups of lines, either one logical line split over more than one physical line (like multiple commands in a `for` or `if` command) or multiple commands on one line *when you change the value of the variable within that block and want to also use it within that block*.

Comment: Yes, I know, @Noodles; the scripts are just intended to demonstrate the strange behaviour...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The options of `FOR`, `IF` and `REM` are only parsed up to the special character phase.
Or better the commands are detected in the special character phase and a different parser is activated then.

Therefore it's not possible to use delayed expansion nor FOR-Parameter in the options.

These tests fail with errors

```
for /F %%O in ("defined") do (
  if %%O var echo yes
)

set option=defined
if !option! var echo yes
```

This seems to work, but uses the wrong delimiters (`D`, `e`, `i`, `l`, `m`, `s`, `y` and `!` )

```
set "myDelims=123"
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=!myDelims!" %%A in ("Hello 1 world") do (
    echo Token1=%%A  Token2=%%B
)
```

And for REM

```
set "help=/?"
REM !HELP!  - No help will be shown
```

Comment: +1, Left unsaid is the obvious fact that you escape ! to prevent delayed expansion. If delayed expansion can never be used in a particular construct, then there is nothing to escape.

Comment: Thank you for the insight! So I understand using `for` variables cannot be used to define parameters for that commands either[.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133) And the `delims` should contain `D` rather than `d`, right?

Comment: @aschipfl Yes, the same applies for `FOR` variables, see the first expamle. Also, you are right with your second part, I fixed the `D`