# Batch For Loop %%i Doesn't Expand

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to get files from folders in batch.
And this is the whole batch file:

```
for %%i in (folder) do echo (for /r "%%~i" %%j in (*.png) do echo %%~i-%%j)
```

The code executes as intended and outputs to console:

```
(for /r "folder" %j in (*.png) do echo folder-%j)
```

If i copy this and paste it as is to a cmd at the same path it echoes my file.

But if i remove the first echo from batch it outputs:

```
(for /R "%~i" %j in (*.png) do echo folder-%j )
```

Note that it doesn't execute the for loop and the second %%i is expanded but first is not. I can't get why this extremely basic one line batch doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why the `echo` before the `for`?  And for that matter why two `FOR` commands?

Comment: `Echo` was for testing after the command didn't work. Two `For`s because i can add multiple folders at the `folder` in the first `for` loop.

Comment: As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39653402) you cannot use a `for` meta-variable as the argument value of `for /R`; as a work-around, put the inner `for /R` loop into a sub-routine, call it by `call` and use an argument reference like `for /R "%~1" in ...`...

Comment: This might actually work. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39653402) you cannot use a `for` meta-variable as an option value of `for /R`. This is because the options are read and parsed before `for` meta-variables are expanded. The `for` command, as well as the `if` and the `rem` command, is recognised earlier than other commands as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133); `for` meta-variables and delayed expansion are both expanded later, so they are read literally when these commands are parsed.

As a work-around, put the inner `for /R` loop into a sub-routine, call it by `call` and use an argument reference like `%~1` to pass over the current value of the outer `for` loop:

```cmd
for %%i in ("folder") do call :SUB "%%~i"
goto :EOF

:SUB
for /R "%~1" %%j in ("*.png") do echo "%~1"-"%%~j"
```