# For loop variable expansion in options of another loop

Tags: batch-file, cmd

This Batch file code snippet

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%i IN (1 2 3) DO (
    ECHO %%i "%%i" %%a "%%a"
    FOR /F "skip=%%i" %%j IN ("abc"
                              "abc"
                              "abc") DO ( ECHO. )
)
```

produces

```
1 "1" %a "%a"
%i" was unexpected at this time.
2 "2" %a "%a"
%i" was unexpected at this time.
3 "3" %a "%a"
%i" was unexpected at this time.
```

`%%i` is expanded properly (to `1`,`2`,`3`) on the third line. However, on the fourth line `%%i` seems to  expand to just `%i`. Apparently, the interpreter does not recognize on the forth line `%%i` as something that needs to be expanded and rather treats `%%` as the usual escape sequence for `%` and `i` just as `i`. Why does it happen? Is it just a bug (the interpreter is just implemented this way) or there is some logic in this behavior? if so, is it mentioned somewhere in the documentation?

Comment: The interpreter is just implemented this way. The command-modifiers in a `for/f` (skip, tokens, etc.) and the start-direcrory in a `for/r` must be able to be resolved at parse-time of the outer loop. Try passing the values to a subroutine.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39653402) should explain why this cannot work…